# converting a local git folder as a remote repository

Tags: windows, git, ssh

sorry if  my question is too naive. Here is what i am trying to do:

- I want to create a local git repo (git init )-> i did that
- I want to access the same form other machines using ssh -> stuck here
- I have tried installing git bash , but i don't know how to configure ssh which is built in the git bash.
- I did add a ssh config file using git bash and gave as my computername along with domain, since this machine is the server here.
- In the git bash guide, they are adding the public key to github, i dont want that
- In short i have created a git repository by 'git init .'
- I want to access the same using other machines in the same domain using ssh

I don't know how to proceed further, Would anyone be able to help in this case ?

Comment: Just google how to log to a remote computer using SSH.

Comment: To clone a Git repository over SSH, you can specify ssh:// URL like this:       git clone ssh://user@server:project.git
Or you can not specify a protocol— Git assumes SSH if you aren’t explicit:       git clone user@server:project.git
You can also not specify a user, and Git assumes the user you’re currently logged in as..

Comment: thanks for your time, are the tasks of configuring ssh and cloning independent in this context ? i have seen posts about adding the public key to github account , but i don't need that here right ?once i generate keys what is the procedure to start ssh ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a `--bare` repository somewhere accessible via SSH and `push`, `fetch`, `merge`, `pull` to and from that repository by adding a remote origin to the ones you created.

Something like

```
/home/git $ git init --bare your_repository.git

/your/current/repository $ git remote add origin /home/git/your_repository.git
```

And from another machine

```
/client/path $ git init
/client/path $ git remote add origin user@server:/home/git/your_repository.git
/client/path $ git pull origin
```

Then

```
/your/current/repository $ git fetch origin
/your/current/repository $ git merge origin/master
/your/current/repository $ git push origin master

/client/path $ git fetch origin
/client/path $ git merge origin/master
/client/path $ git push origin master
```

That's just an example, the `--bare` repository can be anywhere.

Have a look here for pros and cons http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html

Comment: Thanks for your time Kyra, What if i have set up my git repo in folder D? can i give "username@domain:D:/somefolder". Also, which is the better tools for creating ssh server in windows ?

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't know about Windows, sorry.

Comment: Perhaps you might use some GUI

Comment: i tried that, followed the steps there until the part where it says to add the public key to github account, But i want to make my local repo  as the server,and other computers will access my repo using ssh